# Keras's expand_dims function causing tensors to lose metadata

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm having issues using keras's expand_dims function. Here's a simple expample:

This code works:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Input, Lambda
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.python.keras.backend import expand_dims

def add_fun(x):
  return tf.add(x[0], x[1])

in_1 = Input(shape=(None, None, 8))
in_2 = Input(shape=(None, 1, 1))

out = Lambda(add_fun)([in_1, in_2])

m = Model([in_1, in_2], out)
```

And This code does not:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Input, Lambda
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.python.keras.backend import expand_dims

def add_fun(x):
  return tf.add(x[0], x[1])

in_1 = Input(shape=(None, None, 8))
in_2 = Input(shape=(None, 1))

problem_part = expand_dims(in_2, axis=1)

out = Lambda(add_fun)([in_1, problem_part])

m = Model([in_1, in_2], out)
```

As shown [here](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/93730/keras.backend.expand_dims) I believe that I'm using expand_dims correctly, and I can't figure out why its causing a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `expand_dims` is not a Keras layer. If you instead put the call to `expand_dims` inside your lambda layer, then it should work.

Comment: I think we solved this at the same time! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved by wrapping the expand_dims function call in a Lambda:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Input, Lambda
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.python.keras.backend import expand_dims

def add_fun(x):
  return tf.add(x[0], x[1])

in_1 = Input(shape=(None, None, 8))
in_2 = Input(shape=(None, 1))

problem_part = Lambda(lambda x: expand_dims(x, axis=1))(in_2)

out = Lambda(add_fun)([in_1, problem_part])

m = Model([in_1, in_2], out)
```